# Clicking links in newly opened tab using WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Can someone please help me in this scenario:

**Scenario is:** There is a webpage and I am opening all of my specified links in new Tab only. Now I am trying to click any one link in newly opened Tab. Tried below, but it is clicking that one link in the main/first tab only, instead of in new tab.

```
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.NUMPAD1).perform();
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.TAB);
List<WebElement> links=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http')]"));
links.get(0).click();
```

Comment: Can soeone please tell me, how to bring the web driver control/focus to the newly opened Tab and click the links in that tab.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use the `.switchTo(windowHandle);` command to access your second tab.

Before opening the second tab - get the windowHandle of the open tab:

```
String mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

Then do your action that opens the second tab. Now you'll need to know the handle of the second tab and switch control to it:

```
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();  
for (String handle : handles) {
    if (!handle.equals(mainWindow)) {
          driver.switchTo().window(handle);
          break;
    }
}
```

Your actions for the second tab will now happen in that second window. When you're finished and need to interact with the first tab again: `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`

Comment: I have corrected driver.switchTo line inside if statement. It should be driver.switchTo().window(handle); instead of driver.switchTo(handle);

Comment: in my case using driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); did not work. That's why I used driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow); to go to the parent(1st) window.

Comment: How to close the 2nd Tab/Window?